# Оптимизация кода при подсчете совпадений

Tags: java, оптимизация, логика

Есть файл с множеством строк и иногда эти строки повторяются. Нужно повторяющиеся строки слить в одну и в конце(в начале) этой строки написать сколько было слито строк.
P.S. актуально соединять только соседние строчки.
Вот мой набросок:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/1.txt"));
        BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/2.txt"));

        String newLine = "";
        String oldLine = "";
        int count = 2;

        while ((newLine = bReader.readLine()) != null){

            if(!oldLine.equals(newLine)){

                if(count != 2){
                    oldLine = oldLine + (String.format(" (%d times)", count));
                    count = 2;
                }

                if(!oldLine.isEmpty()){
                    bWriter.write(oldLine + "\n");
                }

                oldLine = newLine;

            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        bWriter.write(oldLine);
        bWriter.close();
    }
}
```

1.txt исходный файл, 2.txt результат

```
1.txt   2.txt

111     111
222     222 (3 times)
222     333     
222     444 (2 times)
333     555
444
444
555
```

Comment: А у вас повторяющиеся только по порядку идут? Просто обычно это делают через `hash`, где ключ - это строка. То есть вы считаете количество строк по хэшу.

Comment: Цыфры только для примера. оригинальная строка посложнее и может повторятся в нескольких местах. актуально соединять только соседние строчки

Comment: Какой код вы считаете оптимальным или грамотным? У вас есть критерии или тесты по которым вы определяет грамотность?

Comment: А чем плох ваш вариант? И важное условие "актуально соединять только соседние строчки " надо добавить в вопрос

Comment: Roman: я весьма слаб в програмировании, достиг немного большего чем "Hallo world". То что я использовал для решения задачи требовало, по сути, начального уровня знаний. Вот захотел узнать у более опытных есть ли инструменты/варианты, о которых мне неизвесно.

Comment: MBo, вроде код и не плох и весьма лаконичен, но меня смущает количество проверок, понимаю, что не так уж их и много, но всёже... А по поводу  "актуально соединять только соседние строчки", мой недосмотр.

Comment: зачем ты делаешь проверку `count != 2` и присваиваешь `count = 2;`? IMHO нужно заменить на `count > 1` и `count = 1;`

Comment: dgzargo, да верно. обратил внимание, но уже было поздно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в таких случаюх пользуюсь HashMap: ключем выступает обьект, а значением - счетчик.
В цикле просто проверяем есть ли такой ключ, если да - инкрементируем ему значение.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> lineMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String line = "";

    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
        Integer count = lineMap.get(line);
        if (count == null){                //если строка новая, кладем ее в hashMap со значением '1'
            lineMap.put(line, 1);
        } else {
            lineMap.put(line, ++count);    //если строка есть в хешмапе - увеличиваем значение.
        }
    }
    for (String s:  //пробегаемся по всем ключам (строкам), значения которьх - счетчики повторений
         lineMap.keySet()) {
        line = s + (String.format(" (%d times)\n", lineMap.get(s)));
        bWriter.write(line);
    }
    bWriter.close();
```

Если нужно нумеровать только повторяющиеся строки:

```
    for (String s:  //пробегаемся по всем ключам (строкам), значения которьх - счетчики повторений
         lineMap.keySet()) {
        Integer c = lineMap.get(s);
        line = c == 1? s : s + (String.format(" (%d times)\n", c));
        bWriter.write(line);
    }
    bWriter.close();
```

Comment: Вариант оличный, вот только нумеруются все строки а нужно только повторяющиеся.

Comment: В чем проблема доработать?

Comment: Никакой :)

    line = (lineMap.get(s)==1 ? s + "\n" :s + (String.format(" (%d times)\n", lineMap.get(s))));

Самое очевидное для меня

Comment: Тогда отмечайте ответ, как решение вопроса

Comment: К сожалению отловил баг. Недостаток HashMap в том, что он одинаковые элементы "складывает" в одну ячейку. Не зависимо от того, шли строки подряд или нет. Тоесть если дальше по файлу найдётся снова 1111, то в списке будет отмечено 2  times. В моём случае это неприемлемо. Пока останусь на своём варианте.

Comment: "если дальше по файлу найдется СНОВА 1111, то в списке будет отмечено 2 times". Разве Вам не именно это нужно?

Comment: Valentyn Hruzytskyi, нет, только соседние строки

Answer (score 0):

Ваш алгоритм использует подход "когда строка изменилась, вывести предыдущую и количество её повторов (если оно больше единицы)".

Он **оптимален**, лучше алгоритмически не сделать, никаких дополнительных структур данных не требуется (не исключаю, что какие-то тонкости возможны в java реализации)

Недостаток (про count 1 уже подсказал @dgzargo), насколько я понимаю - не обрабатывается последний набор строк

`bWriter.write(oldLine);`  не выводит count если он больше 1, а надо. Просто добавить такие же условия? как внутри цикла.